# returned value from fget(filePointer) doesn't changed

Tags: c, fgetc

I try to extract a char by using `unsigned char ch1 = fgetc(filePointer);`, but the value that's returned is allways `255`. Here's my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "anotherCFile.c"
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int ch;
    FILE* filePointer;
    filePointer = fopen("text.txt", "w+");
    ch = fgetc(stdin);
    while (ch!=EOF) {
        fputc(ch, filePointer);
        ch = fgetc(stdin);
}
    unsigned char ch1 = fgetc(filePointer);
    fclose(filePointer);
    printf("%c", ch1);
    return 0;
}
```

For any input I've checked (s.a. `ABC`) the output is `�`. When I change the line `printf("%c", ch1);` to `printf("%d", ch1);` the output is always `255`. I want to get the chars I've entered in the input.

(The `text.txt` file is created properly). Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the time of `unsigned char ch1 = fgetc(filePointer);` `filepointer` points to `EOF(-1)` and in next statement you are printing `ASCII` value of that which is `255(bcz ch is declared as unsigned)`.

`EOF` defined as `#define EOF (-1)`

```
printf("%c\n,ch1); /* EOF is not printable char so it prints � */
printf("%d\n",ch1); /* fgetc() returns int, As char read is stored in a
                     variable of type int and that is EOF,and -1 
                     equivalent unsigned value is 255 */
```

*I want to get the chars I've entered in the input.* ? do `rewind() or fseek()` before reading.

```
 rewind(filepointer);/* this is required to get first char of file */
 unsigned char ch1 = fgetc(filePointer);
 fclose(filePointer);
 printf("%c", ch1);
```

Comment: `fgetc` returns an **int**.

Comment: yes @AnttiHaapala `fgetc()` returns `int` that is `-1` in that statement and its assigned to `ch1` which is declared as `unsigned char`

Comment: This is to point out that *you* should know better and show that the character read is stored in a variable of type `int` :D

Answer (score 1):

When you write to a `*FILE ptr`, its pointer is advanced and set to the end of file, ready to append the next char.
To read some data back without reopening the file and reusing the same file pointer, you may want to rewind the pointer first.

Try to add

```
fseek(filePointer, 0, SEEK_SET);
```

before reading the data back